# Why is my HomePod mini chosen over my Apple TV 4K as a Home Hub?

Tags: appletv, homekit, homepod

I have an AppleTV 4K (2nd) and a pair of HomePod minis, but one of my HomePod minis is always chosen as my HomeKit Home Hub. Is there a way to prioritize the AppleTV as a Home Hub instead? Why is one of the HomePods always preferred as the hub?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot select which hub is active and which are on standby. If the HomePod becomes disconnected then your Apple TV will automatically become the hub.